# VerifyError on Tomcat 7 production server probably caused by Apache Commons Logging 1.0.4

Tags: java, tomcat7, apache-commons, apache-fop

I'm developing webapp on Tomcat 7. Everything works **fine on my local version** of Tomcat, but when I deploy it on production server, it throws this exception.

```
java.lang.VerifyError: (class: org/apache/commons/logging/impl/Log4JLogger, method: fatal signature: (Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Throwable;)V) Incompatible object argument for function call
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2595)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2895)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:1731)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.getLogConstructor(LogFactoryImpl.java:410)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.newInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:529)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.getInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:235)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.getInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:209)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:351)
    at org.apache.fop.apps.FopFactory.<clinit>(FopFactory.java:68)
    at cz.soma.tomcat.generator.DokumentaceUtils.createPdfDocument(DokumentaceUtils.java:818)
    at cz.soma.tomcat.generator.FileFactory.createPdfDocument(FileFactory.java:58)
    at cz.soma.tomcat.generator.Generator.doPost(Generator.java:111)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
```

The error is thrown, when I try to `FopFactory.newInstance();` (from Apache FOP 1.0). After that, it tries to `LogFactory.getLog(FopFactory.class);`. It causes, that `logClass.getConstructor(logConstructorSignature);` is called, where logConstructorSignature contains one String.class. (at least on my local machine)

```
try {
    logConstructor = logClass.getConstructor(logConstructorSignature);
    return (logConstructor);
} catch (Throwable t) {
    throw new LogConfigurationException
        ("No suitable Log constructor " +
         logConstructorSignature+ " for " + logClassName, t);
}
```

After this are called the java.lang.Class functions and thrown exception.
Have you any idea, why the error is only thrown on production server, but not on my local machine?

Comment: Seems like some problem with commons-logging version difference between your local and prod env. How do you deploy your application?

Comment: @evere10 By sending war package to Tomcat Web Application Manager. How would it be possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### **Why this error(java.lang.VerifyError) occurs?**

**java.lang.VerifyError** would be the result when you have compiled against a different library than you are using at runtime(in your production server).

### Suggestion#1:

You can use `commons-logging-1.1.1.jar` instead of `commons-logging-1.0.4.jar`. Then rebuild your project and check.

**Resource Link:** http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=674

### Suggestion#2:

If you are using maven,then **add this dependency** in your pom.xml,

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

and **remove the following dependency** from your pom.xml

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.4</version>
</dependency>
```

**Resource Link:** [Getting java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1551697/getting-java-lang-classnotfoundexception-org-apache-commons-logging-logfactory)

### Suggestion#3:

[templatetypedef](https://stackoverflow.com/users/501557/templatetypedef) has dig the issue and give 2 solutions

> A VerifyError usually means that you loaded in a class file that is
>   somehow malformed or which references another class file that has
>   changed in a way that causes the code in another class file to no
>   longer be valid. For example, if you compiled a class file that
>   referenced a method in some other class, then independently modified
>   and recompiled the second class after altering that method's
>   signature, you'd get this sort of error.
>
> I'd suggest doing a clean build and seeing if this issue goes away. If
>   not, check whether you're using up-to-date JARs and source files.

**Resource Link:** https://stackoverflow.com/a/5411528/2293534

### Suggestion#4:

If your JDK version mismatch between local and production server, then make it same if possible. You may also try compiling with a different JDK version and on a different machine.

**Resource Link:** [Causes of getting a java.lang.VerifyError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100107/causes-of-getting-a-java-lang-verifyerror)

Hopefully it will help you.

Comment: I don't know why, but the problem has been solved, when I transformed it to maven project and set dependences. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You probably have a different version of the logging jars in the common lib directory on the production Tomcat server.  Have someone check the \lib directory and see if there are any logging jars in the lib directory.  Either remove those jars so your local app jars are used or make sure the same version of dependencies are being defined in your application.

If you want to try reproducing locally replicate the set of jars in the production lib directory to your local install.